# Laravel - traducir aplicación

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-blade

tengo un backend con laravel (blade) y estoy intentando activar las traducciones, para ello he
hecho lo siguiente

```
Route::get('lang/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    if (! in_array($locale, ['en', 'es', 'fr'])) {
        abort(400);
    }

    App::setLocale($locale);

    return view('pages.login');

})->name('front.pages.change-language');
```

Con este método lo que hago es "setear" el local mediante unos iconos que tengo en el frontal de este tipo

```
   <a style="color:white!important;" href="{{route('front.pages.change-language',['es']) }}">ESP</a> 
  <a style="color:white!important;" href="{{route('front.pages.change-language',['en']) }}">ENG</a>
```

En el momento de darle al link veo como la página a la cual "redirige" si me sale en el idioma seleccionado, pero el resto de páginas no, no se si debo setearlo en sesión y luego recuperar ese valor...no lo tengo claro.

Y otra duda relacionado con lo mismo, cuando pulso sobre el botón de un idioma lo que hago es "redigir" a la página de login, como puedo hacer en la misma función para que "recargue" o redirija a la página (uri) sobre la cual esta el usuario en ese momento?

gracias

Comment: Dentro de tu proyecto debes tener los archivos de traducción para que dentro de la carpeta config en app cambies la variable con la cual cambiaras el idioma.

Comment: En la ruta que muestras no deberías establecer el locales `App::setLocale($locale);` en su lugar deberías guardarlo en session o en BD y redirigir a la última vista. Luego crear un middleware que es el que se va a encargar de establecer el locale en `App::setLocale($locale);` según la session del usuario.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, intenta con esta solucion de Povilas Korop.
[Multi-Language Routes and Locales with Auth](https://laraveldaily.com/multi-language-routes-and-locales-with-auth/)

Como tambie esta la solución de Shanika Wickramasinghe.
[Laravel localization: A step-by-step guide](https://lokalise.com/blog/laravel-localization-step-by-step/)

Comment: Hola Intelguasoft, aunque esta respuesta puede servir para guiar al usuario al solucionar la pregunta, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Las publicaciones que son básicamente enlaces se consideran de baja calidad porque si el enlace se rompe, dejan de tener sentido. Por favor, edita la respuesta para poner las partes claves de las páginas enlazadas en la propia respuesta (manteniendo el enlace como referencia). Lee [answer] y visita el [tour] para más información y recomendaciones.